# Where should I ask questions regarding the Linux kernel?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I was wondering if I can ask Linux kernel questions on Stack Overflow? For example, my current question about being unable to insert a new kernel module due to an "Unknown symbol" error.

If not, what site would be appropriate for such questions?

Comment: Better to ask here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/ SO is only for programming.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is only for programming based questions, the best site to ask questions about the Linux kernel would be [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: SO is still good to ask questions about actual kernel / module code as long as it is about programming.

Comment: How about Superuser?

Comment: @bbaassssiiee I couldn't say, I am not familiar with Superusers rules.